# what is the most efficient way to clear an atomic reference to stringbuilder

Tags: java, atomic, stringbuilder

If i have an AtomicReference to a StringBuilder defined as so:

```
private AtomicReference<StringBuilder> stringBuffer = new AtomicReference<>(new StringBuilder());
```

which method is best for clearing it

```
this.stringBuffer.set(new StringBuilder());
```

or

```
this.stringBuffer.getAndUpdate(ref -> {
       ref.setLength(0);
       return ref;
  });
```

Comment: Best or effecient, what does best mean? Why do you think one is more effecient than the other? Why does it matter?

Comment: I meant efficient space and complexity wise. I'd assume the second is more efficient? but not sure @ScaryWombat

Comment: The `AtomicReference` seems irrelevant to your Question. Aren't you really just asking if clearing an existing `StringBuilder` is "better" than instantiating a fresh one? (a) How do you see `AtomicReference` being an issue here? (b) Define "better". (c) *Premature optimization is the root of all evil* — Donald Knuth

Comment: The entire point of `AtomicReference` is to protect access across threads. Wouldn't instantiating just to clear the content confuse matters with those other threads that may be counting on the content of that `StringBuilder`?

Comment: The methods are not even equivalent: one changes the reference to a new string builder, the other removes the content of the existing string builder. And the second method looks fishy – why not `stringBuffer.get().setLength(0)`? Note that `setLength(0)` is _not_ protected by the atomicref (neither with `get` nor with `getAndUpdate`)

Answer (score 3):

The second form is incorrect and should not be used. The thread safety properties of `AtomicReference` do not provide thread safety to concurrent modification and access of the object it references, only the reference itself. In general, you must take care when using an `AtomicReference` with a mutable object, and arguably it should only be used with immutable objects (such as `String`) when possible.

Further, the documentation for the [`getAndUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getAndUpdate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method is clear that the function provided must be free of side effects. In this case, the call to `ref.setLength(0)` is considered a side effect.

Since [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is not intrinsically thread safe, sharing an instance between multiple threads requires synchronization or a similar form of locking to prevent concurrent modification and access.

Alternatively, the [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) class is thread safe when used correctly.

If using an `AtomicReference<StringBuffer>` instead of `AtomicReference<StringBuilder>`, you could safely clear it like this:

```
this.stringBuffer.get().setLength(0)
```

This has different semantics than replacing the reference with a new `StringBuffer` like this:

```
this.stringBuffer.set(new StringBuffer())
```

The difference is in how other concurrent users of the `StringBuffer` will be affected. In the first case, since the existing instance is cleared, other concurrent references to it will also be affected. In the second case, other threads that have a reference to the original `StringBuffer` will continue to see the previous value. Depending on how the value is used in the program, one or the other of these behaviours might be incorrect.

Another difference is that the first version may block if another thread currently holds the lock on the `StringBuffer`, while the second version will never block. If there is heavy contention on the `StringBuffer`, this could slow down the first version.

If the previous value in the `StringBuffer` occupied a large amount of memory, `setLength` does not free that internal memory. So it avoids an additional allocation, but may mean that more heap space is consumed than required.

On the other hand, the second version will allocate a new object. If there are other references retained to the original `StringBuffer`, it will continue to occupy additional heap space. When no other references remain, it creates garbage that needs to be cleared.

So, the performance characteristics are hard to predict out of context. They'll depend on the amount of contention and memory pressure, the frequency that this operation is performed, and the way the application uses the object after retrieving it from the `AtomicReference`. The difference is probably negligible for most applications. You'll need to benchmark your own application to be certain.